# How to read csv file from Sharepoint in a databricks notebook

Tags: azure, sharepoint, databricks

Is there a way to read a csv file from a sharepoint folder inside a databricks notebook?
Any pointers would be really helpful. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There is no direct option yet.

The other two Alternatives:

1. using Azure Logic Apps(if Microsoft Azure cloud) or use AWS Lambda(if AWS cloud) to move files from SharePoint to ADLS/S3 Storage and consuming files from there via mount options. - **its recommended** and in use by most now.
2. 3rd party services - [Process & Analyze SharePoint Data in Databricks (AWS)](https://www.cdata.com/kb/tech/sharepoint-jdbc-aws-databricks.rst) - not sure reg this option under quality, safety, or suitability as per microsoft.